# get attribute option value in magento 2.1 using helper in module data.php

Tags: magento2, php-5.4

Ex : Manufacturer attribute code, i want to access selected manufacturer option value , by creating a function or method in helper file in module.
can anyone please suggest me the code.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your helper class ::

```
public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
    array $data = [] 
    ){        
    parent::__construct($context,$data);
    $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
} 

public function getAllManufacturer(){
    $manufacturerOptions = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('manufacturer')->getOptions();       
    $values = array();
    foreach ($manufacturerOptions as $manufacturerOption) { 
       //$manufacturerOption->getValue();  // Value
        $values[] = $manufacturerOption->getLabel();  // Label
    }
    return $values;
}
```

//get option label based on option id

```
$optionId = $_product->getData('color');


$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
 if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
 }
```

Comment: thank you , how to return this method in list.phtml in  this code in ancher tag          <strong class="product name product-item-name"> <a class="product-item-link"   href="<?php  echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>                                
                            </a>
                        </strong>

Comment: add this method in any of any of your custom module block file and create the object of that block in list.phtml.

Comment: actually color attribute i want to return in anchar tag instead of manufacturer, every product title color is having selected different color, so how can i return helfer method in list.phtml file.

Comment: Not clear how you want to create anchar tag, but pl check my updated answer if this resolve your issue.

Comment: can you let me know , how to create object in list.phtml file , and how to return in anchar tag in id=" " 
<strong id= " here i want to return that object" class="product name product-item-name"> <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?> </a> </strong>

Comment: $_titlecolor = $_product->getAllManufacturer(); like this i have created object in list.phtml, its not retriving . can u check and tell me how to create object in list.phtml file in magento 2.1

Comment: Use this :: $_titlecolor =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Comment: i have created helper class in data.php
namespace Sundial\Producttitlecolor\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
 public function getAllColor($_product){
  $color = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);   
  return $color;
 }
}
and i have retrieved in list.phtml file using this code$_titlecolor = $this->helper('Sundial\Producttitlecolor\Helper\Data');      
       $_titlecolortet = $_titlecolor->getAllColor($_product);
       echo "Hello".$_titlecolortet;